# How to show products of a particular category in a page of Bigcommerce(blueprint framework)?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm working with a theme of bigcommerce that was built with blueprint framework. I want to show a particular category products on a page. But I can't find any variables or syntax to target a particular category.

Is it possible to show products of particular category of bigcommerce in a page?

Comment: on a page? home page ?....

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've checked 2 days after asking the question and didn't saw any response. So I've stopped to check. Yes, I need this on both home page and another specific page.

Comment: you can call category by ajax on the homepage I cannot show you 
 because bigcommerce remove blueprint themes so it's no longer available in new trial store. it is available in old store and I have not any old store so with the help I can send you full code for example.